# Query specific ID's in a firebase year/month/day nest

Tags: firebase, database-design, angularfire, nosql

I have some data structured like the following in firebase. My client is built with angularjs + angularfire.

'all_records' is nested like this to split the data up and also as the majority of the querying is time orientated.

The 'all_records' nest is equal to: all_records > year > month > date > records.

I want to associate the records with the user that posted the record and therefore on record creation have saved the associated ID to the user in 'my_records'.

This example is obviously a very small dataset however to allow for scalability and potentially having having hundreds of thousands of records what would be the best way to query 'all_records' to get just the users 'my_records'.

Thanks

```
all_records : {

    2015 : {
        2 : {
            3: {
                -JgJJaLaL7LuuRL_IO7c : {
                    data: big data;
                },
                -JgJfaOsyfZe_mZPTApA : {
                    data: lots of data;
                },
                ...
            },
            ...
        },
        1 : {
            28 : {
                -JgJJaLaL7kddEl_ddfE : {
                    data: some more data;
                }
            },
            27 : {
                -JgJfadkdjEk_mZPTApA : {
                    data: even more;
                }
            },
            ...

        },
        ...
    },

    2014 : {
        12 : {
            24: {
                -JgJmnvkFdqc_y63lqcv : {
                    data: decemeber data;
                },
                -JgK6xbXY_E58lshaiVa : {
                    data: and a bit more data;
                }
            },
            ...
        },
        11 : {
            ...
        },
        ...
    }
}

user: {
    name : James,
    my_records : {
        -JgK6xbXY_E58lshaiVa: true,
        -JgJJaLaL7LuuRL_IO7c: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your user's `my_records` currently doesn't contain enough information to to directly map to the record. You'd need to add the date (year, month and day) to the information to allow a direct lookup.

I would instead structure things differently:

1. a list of just the records with their `push`-generated `-J` key
2. a list of users, with references to their records
3. a list/tree of dates, with references to the records for each date

Your application should **never** try to load the list of all records (#1). Instead it should load either the relevant user (from #2) or the relevant date(s) from (#3) and then load *only* the records that are referenced from there.

```
all_records : {
    -JgJJaLaL7LuuRL_IO7c : { data: big data; },
    -JgJfaOsyfZe_mZPTApA : { data: lots of data; },
    -JgJJaLaL7kddEl_ddfE : { data: some more data; }
    -JgJfadkdjEk_mZPTApA : { data: even more; }
}

dates: {
    2015 : {
        2 : {
            3: {
                -JgJJaLaL7LuuRL_IO7c : true,
                -JgJfaOsyfZe_mZPTApA : true,
                ...
            },
            ...
        },
        1 : {
            28 : {
                -JgJJaLaL7kddEl_ddfE : true
            },
            27 : {
                -JgJfadkdjEk_mZPTApA : true
            },
            ...
        },
        ...
    }
}

user: {
    name : James,
    my_records : {
        -JgK6xbXY_E58lshaiVa: true,
        -JgJJaLaL7LuuRL_IO7c: true
    }
}
```

You might also want to consider structuring the dates as a simple list, instead of a tree:

```
dates: {
    20150203: {
        -JgJJaLaL7LuuRL_IO7c : true,
        -JgJfaOsyfZe_mZPTApA : true,
        ...
    },
    20150128 : {
        -JgJJaLaL7kddEl_ddfE : true
    },
    20150127 : {
        -JgJfadkdjEk_mZPTApA : true
    },
}
```

While it's tempting to build a tree for the dates, I doubt you'll get much benefit from it. The above structure is simpler and allow for a wider variety of queries, such as "give me all dates in Q1 of 2015": `ref.child('dates').startAt('20150101').endAt('20150331')`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea's frank. So taking your example above I query by date or by a users "my_records" which will give me a list of recordID's. How do I then use this to query "all_records".

Comment: The only way I can see doing it is putting the result of the first query through a loop and for each querying "all_records" ref.equalTo(id) ? Thanks

Comment: That would work, but a direct lookup (instead of a query with `equalTo`) will be more efficient: `ref.child('all_records').child(id).once('value', function(snapshot) { console.log(snapshot.val()); });`

Comment: I see, of course! And this should scale without headache if "all_records" potentially has hundreds of thousand entries? Also say a user had for argument ten thousand "my_records" would performing ten thousand queries in a loop to retrieve all their data be viable? Thanks for the help, still getting my head around nosql!